# Is it possible to work with org-mode tables inside org-babel source blocks as if they were placed directly in an org-file?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Imagine we have the following content of an org-file:

```
|       | Col 1 | Col 2 |
| row 1 |       |       |
| row 2 |       |       |

#+name: Table1
#+begin_src org
|       | Col 1 | Col 2 |
| row 1 |       |       |
| row 2 |       |       |
#+end_src
```

With the former table I can do a lot convenient things
like swapping rows or columns etc.

When working with a table inside the source block (the latter table) all
the useful commands and shortcuts are disabled.
It would be extremely convenient to have them enabled, wouldn't it? But how can I
achieve that?

Comment: Why are you putting `org-tables` inside source blocks?

Comment: I want to generate several other documents with the same table as a content. My idea is to write the content of those documents also in source blocks with my table included with the use of noweb by <<Table1>>. Then I can easily tangle them. Do you have a simpler approach?

Comment: Yes, there are various ways to do that. The most common is to name your table, put  `#+name: Table1` just above the table, then in the file where you want to have it, use `#+include: "PATH/FILE_NAME.org::Table1"`

Comment: Also [org-transclusion](https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion) might be useful.

Comment: It guess it may be a dumb question but I cannot find the answer on the net nor figure it out by myself: "How can I use `#include` approach to include org content within _the_same_ file?"

Comment: `#+include: "./FILE_NAME.org::Table1"`. [See documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Include-Files.html).

Comment: You're right. I knew it should be easy and I was aware of the page you linked but couldn't find out what is the right syntax when including parts of the code within a single file. Both nnzi's answer and your comments are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run `org-edit-special` when in the src block.

You will then a proper org mode "side-buffer" with all the command

This is bound to `C-c '` by default.